# Экранирование текста перед выводом или перед сохранением?

Tags: html, htmlspecialchars

Терзают сомнения какой подход более правильный.

Если сохранить уже экранированный текст то его каждый раз при выводе не нужно будет экранировать, но в сети очень много сообщений о том что экранировать текст необходимо непосредственно перед выводом.

Например, сообщение которое сохранил пользователь в БД:
`Для SEO оптимизации очень важен тэг <title> ...`

Если такой текст поместить посередине страницы, браузер распознает его как не валидный и не будет его отображать.

Как лучше сделать полностью безопасный текст?

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые не осознают, что жизненный цикл *данных* принципиально отличается от жизненного цикла *кода*.

Предположим, разработчица Наташа разбирает случай персистентной XSS-атаки на вебсервер, при котором были украдены данные клиентов, и видит, что все данные экранируются при сохранении, тем не менее.

Наташе не полегчало, когда она увидела, что файл SaveCommentOperation.cpp никогда не менялся в репозитории Git.

Оказывается, что он был создан всего пол года до этого разработчиком Васей, и заменил функцию saveComment в файле AllCommentOperations.cpp, в которой отсутствовало экранирование.

Проект был запущен два года назад, и подозреваемый Кулхацкер успел инициировать персистентную атаку, вставив свой тег `script`. Это была стадия прототипа, и никто не думал, что данные будут жить так долго...

- Перед выводом нужно экранировать обязательно, так как в общем случае неизвестно, какие данные у вас уже сохранены в базе.
- За сохранение в базе данных в общем случае отвечает ограниченный контекст, в котором невозможно предусмотреть особенности всех контекстов использования. Например, для предотвращения атак XSS нужно учитывать особенности HTML-элемента, URL, скрипта, комментария, стиля, аттрибута, аргументов функций JavaScript. Для предотвращения атаки на логи (это когда админ листает логи в терминале, под рутом, и вдруг исполняется код злоумышленника) нужно учитывать что-то совсем другое. Атаковать можно даже с помощью Excel-документа, выводя макросы. Атаковать можно базу данных... Во всех этих случаях, (а они могут все разом быть в одном проекте), нужно экранировать по разному.
- Экранировать при сохранеении даже немножко вредно, так как чей-то дурацкий `sanitizer` испортит код злоумышленника, и потом будет труднее разбираться, как была реализована атака.
- Это попросту дубликация кода, и ложное ощущение защищенности.

... перед тем как начать экранировать вывод, наши неудачники решили перечитать [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Потом тим-лид Петя заикнулся, что нужно экранировать пользовательский ввод, перед тем как составить строки в единое целое для запроса в базу данных, и Наташа кинула в него резиновой свиньей, которую ей подарили на 8-е марта.

После этого его отправили читать про то, что это не считается, так как ничего не гарантирует: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3:_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input

Ему также сообщили, что все нормальные ребята уже давно используют библиотеки доступа к данным, которые поддерживают *параметры*.

Comment: Вы хотите сохранять данные без редактирования, но так же кто то может почистить Вам базу данных, или еще что не то.

Comment: Вы вообще о чем? Если о коде, подверженом SQL инъекциям, то вам сюда: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3:_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input

Comment: не что не чего не гарантирует. По поводу данных которые уже лежат в БД, у Вас есть миграции и возможность привести их все к одинаковому виду. Ваша история очень веселая, но как по мне далека от продуктовой разработки, но идеально описывает аутсор, там где есть какноны и мода. И пофигу, некто не о чем не думает даелает как написано в Ваших ссылках.